# Publishing components/pages in SDL Tridion

Tags: tridion, tridion-content-delivery

I have a question with regards to publishing items in SDL Tridion R5.3.

When we publish an item say a component or page- all the related items would also be published. Well- my question if the component is being used in an older version of a page (not in current version of page), How would the publish process looks like?

I can say the page is not using the component now and hence no way the page should be published. Would this page be avoided in the first stage of publish (in transport) or in a later stage?

Just wanted to get an expert idea on this. I'm trying to improve publish performance in Tridion R5.3. There are as many 500 related items associated with single component publish and it contains related older version items too.

Answer (score 4):

When you publish a component, you will also RE-Publish (Note the **"Re"**):

- All pages where that component is used, paired with a non dynamic CT are Re-Published.
- All components where the published component is used.

You will not Re-Publish:

- Pages where the component was used on older versions
- Non published pages

Also note, that when you publish a page, no other pages will be republished by the default functionality

Performance-wise, the main risk of this publish propagation, is that you publish a component, that is used in other component, and this second component is used in a third component... and so on. Triggering with an innocent component publication a whole site republishing.

This said, beware of component collections.

Comment: Thanks Puntero for the quick turn around. I understand your point completely! I was just looking at the way the system is set up and I see one single componet contains 500 related items. I know these kind of situations are best handled in dynamic component presentation but the way it is built currently is static. That being said, a single component publish, pushes 500 related pages (which are already in published status) to republish. Is there any better way to optimize the publish process?

Comment: Well, you could stop link resolving using event system. But you need to understand what you are doing. As an idea, maybe if you have an schema containing a huge amount of links, you can disable link resolving for that specific schema. You can find more info about this on Nuno's article: http://nunolinhares.blogspot.nl/2011/10/tridion-publisher-and-custom-resolvers.html

Comment: Thats a great piece of information Puntero. Let me look in to Nuno's article. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: +1 for beware of component collections. Lots of component linking is usually a sign of a poor design.

Comment: I agree with you Dominic. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Puntero pointed out it's the "Used By" items that are already published that get published. A single item used 500 suggests an opportunity to "template" its use, even if you don't go dynamic. A checkbox or field could drive logic to include that content. Also it might make sense to only publish pages.

Comment: Related "uses" multimedia components _may_ get published based on template logic. This is separate from the link propagation scenario. You can always tell what's queued by checking the "see items to publish" box in the publishing pop-up.

Comment: Thank you Alvin. When I click on "Items to Publish" in publish popup, I could many items referenced and some of them were older version files. Means- the current component is no longer attached to the newer version of the reference component. I'm confused why Tridion is sending the old versioned files in the package. This causes additional burden to the package adding lot of binaries. You have a thought on this? Appreciate your help. Thanks, KK

Comment: Hmm, I don't see the same. On my SDL Tridion 2011 SP1-1 setup, removing a component from a page and publishing the component doesn't queue the previously referencing page. Maybe the functionality's changes since R5.3 (in a way it might be helpful to have pages that used to link to your component get updated for you).  To reduce the number of multimedia that publish, consider adjusting the templates that are publishing them.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the documentation explains on what get's published or unpublished. Even though the document is for 2011 SP1, applicable for previous Tridion versions.

http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_56BCD7B2A1994C76B940751B2458D8E0

**Publish/RePublish:**

- If a Component has already been published and is embedded on a Page, all published Pages in which the Component is used are republished.
- If a Component is based on an allowed Schema that is used in a dynamic Component Template(s), only the dynamic Component Presentation(s) is/are published.
- Any Components that link to the Component you publish are also republished.

**Unpublish:**

- All published Pages which use the Component are unpublished.
- If a Component is used in one or more dynamic Component Presentations, the dynamic Component Presentations are unpublished.